# How should I use `json field` in where clause in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a json field in postgresql table `feeAmount`:

```
            feeAmount              |  id
------------------------------------+---------------
                                    | 001
 {"value": null, "currency": "AUD"}  | 002
 {"value": "5", "currency": "AUD"}  | 003
```

I'd like to query rows whose `feeAmount -> value` is not null. Some rows may be null for the entire `feeAmount` field. some rows' `feeAmount` has a json data whose value is null. They need to be excluded.

I have tried this query:

```
select "feeAmount" from "Transactions" where "feeAmount"->'value' is not null;
select "feeAmount" from "Transactions" where "feeAmount"->'value'::text is not null;
```

but both of the queries return the rows

```
{"value": null, "currency": "AUD"}  | 002
```

how can I exclude the value: null from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `feeAmount->'value'` returns string `null` of json type

you can try cast `feeAmount->'value'` as string type before comparing.

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions
WHERE (
 feeAmount->'value' is not null
AND 
 (feeAmount->'value')::text <> 'null'
)
```

or simple way use `coalesce` compare which row didn't equal `null` text.

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions
WHERE coalesce(feeAmount->'value','null') <> 'null'
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=583cdd568e61ccd358db5f472178aca4)

Answer (score 1):

That would work like this:

```
WHERE "feeAmount" -> 'value' <> JSONB 'null'
```

(Use `JSON` instead of `JSONB` is your data type is `json`.)

That will exclude those rows where `value` is set to `null`. If you walso want to exclude rows where `value` is not set at all, you'd be better of with

```
WHERE "feeAmount" ->> 'value' IS NOT NULL
```